# What is the Big-Ω of the following function?

Tags: asymptotics

For the following function:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2n}x+x^2
$$

It is easy to see the (tightest) Big-Oh is $O(n^3)$, but I am not so sure about the Big-Omega. Here is my attempt:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2n}x+x^2
$$
$$
\geq \sum_{n=1}^{2n}x^2
$$

But not sure how to continue. Also, does tightest Big-Ω always equal tightest Big-Oh?

EDIT: The way I worked out the Big-Oh is shown below:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2n}x+x^2
$$
$$
\leq \sum_{n=1}^{2n}x^2+x^2
$$
$$
= \sum_{n=1}^{2n}2x^2
$$
$$
\leq 2n ( 2(2n)^2)
$$
$$
= 8n^3
$$

Therefore the Big-Oh is $O(n^3)$.

Comment: Please show in the question how "to see the (tightest) Big-$O$ is $O(n^3)$".

Comment: @Apass.Jack Updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{x=1}^{2n}(x+x^2) \gt \sum_{x=1}^{2n}x^2 \gt \sum_{x=n+1}^{2n}x^2\gt\sum_{x=n+1}^{2n}n^2= n^3
\end{align}
$$

So the function is $\Omega(n^3)$. You have shown it is $O(n^3)$. So the function is $\Theta(n^3)$.

Although $n^3$, the asymptotic lower bound ignoring a constant factor is the same as the asymptotic upper bound ignoring a constant factor in the current case, it is not always true because some functions fluctuate. For example,
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}1 \quad \text {when }n\text{ is odd,}\\ n \quad \text{when }n\text{ is even.}\end{cases}$$ $f(n)=O(n)$ and $f(n)=\Omega(1)$. Both bounds are tightest.

---

**Exercise.** Show that $$\sum_{x=1}^{m}(x+x^2)=\frac{m(m+1)(m+2)}{3}$$

Comment: @TigerHix The fact that $O$ and $\Omega$ can be different, btw, is why $\Theta$ exists.

Comment: @Draconis That's a bit of a non-sequitur. There are situations where there may be a "nice" $\Theta$-class (unlike for $f$ in the answer) but we can't prove tight bounds. Then, we need $O$ and $\Omega$ to express that what we _can_ prove.

Comment: @Raphael Sorry, what I'm saying is that if $O$ and $\Omega$ were always the same, there'd be no reason to have $\Theta$ as its own thing.

Comment: @Draconis I understood that, and I disagree. (If anything, it'd be a reason to have only $\Theta$; arguably, $\Theta$ _is_ redundant.)